# Geolocation and php and database

Tags: php, geolocation, mysqli

I want to use geolocation in my phpwebsite. So what have I done. Users can add information like name, STREET, HOUSENUMBER, ... to a database. This information is clearly stored in the database. If people look for a place with the searchfunction they receive a list of places they searched for. 
On every founded place at the list, users can click on en they receive a more detailed page about a specific place(record). In this page there has to be geolocation. I already used google and I discovered i need to convert the adress to a lattidude/longitude. This lattitude and longitude must be added to the database but i don't know at what moment (already in the add function, after in a seperate function) and how am i going to do this. At this moment i have a function that calculate the longitude and latitude. I stored them into 2 variables, in javascript but now i'm stuck.
Here you see the code i already have.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 
    // wire up button click
    $('#go').click(function () {
        // get the address the user entered
        var straat = $('#straat').val();
        var nummer = $('#nummer').val();
        var address = straat + " " + nummer;
        alert(address);
        if (address) {
            // use Google Maps API to geocode the address
            // set up the Geocoder object
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            // return the coordinates
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        // print results
                        printLatLong(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                           results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    } else {
                        error('Google did not return any results.');
                    }
 
                } else {
                    error("Reverse Geocoding failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            error('Please enter an address');
        }
    });
 
});
 
// output lat and long
function printLatLong(lat, long) {
    var latitude = lat;
    var longitude = long;
    $('.results').text(latitude);
}
 
function error(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you save those other fields to your database?  Why not geocode and store the lat and long at that same point?

Comment: That's what i want to do but i don't know how. I have a full php script that stores al my information BUT NOT the LONG/LAT. I want to store this at the same time but how.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you can geocode with PHP (google has a rest API you can either hit with file_get_contents or cURL) and if you do that in the original save, you'll have those data points

Comment: Ok so to check if u understand everything. I can use geocode without using javascript due to the rest api from google. I just have to use file_get_contest or cURL?

Comment: Correct. It'll give you back JSON, which you can json_decode, so that you can work with it to get to just the pieces you need

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Are you showing a Google map here? It's against Google's TOS to use the Geocoder without showing a Google Map to the user (just FYI).

Comment: Good point, that applies to the caching as well...only okay if the ultimate destination is a google map